# Why isn't the Boolean value recognized?

Tags: java

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(string[] args) {
        boolean found;
        String[] caseArray = new caseArray {
            "apple", "orange", "mango", "pineapple"
        } ;
        for (int i = 0; i < caseArray.length; i++) {
            if (caseArray[i].equals("pineapple")) {
                found = true;
                break;
            } else {
                found = false;
            }
        }
        if (found == true) {
            System.out.println("product found");
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.print("product not found");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code I would like to return found = true when the for loop searches pineapple in the array. If found is equal to true I would like it to print "product found", if found = false I would like it to print "product not found".

Comment: Please format the code properly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this will compile, because of your uninitialized boolean variable. In the case of a 0 length array, the found boolean will never get initialed, and Java won't let you do that

```
public class HelloWorld{

    public static void main(string [] args){

    boolean found = false;

    String [] caseArray = new caseArray{"apple", "orange", "mango", "pineapple" };

    for(int i = 0; i< caseArray.length; i++){

                                    if(caseArray[i].equals(pineapple)){

                                        found = true;
                                        break;
                                    } else{

                                        found = false;
                                    }

                                }

                                if(found == true){

                                    System.out.println("product found");
                                    break;

                                } else {
                                    System.out.print("product not found");
                                    break;
                                }    

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not follow the java grammar correctly.
This will work.

```
public class HelloWorld{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        boolean found = false;
        String[] caseArray = new String[]{"apple", "orange", "mango", "pineapple" };

        for(int i = 0; i< caseArray.length; i++) {
            if(caseArray[i].equals("pineapple")) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        
        if(found == true) {
            System.out.println("product found");
        } else {
            System.out.print("product not found");
        }
    }
}
```

On your post, those are not following the grammar.
First, on your code

```
public static void main(string[] args) {
```

On above code, args is `string[]` (small `s` first) and it should be uppercase. (`String[]`)

Second, on your code

```
String[] caseArray = new caseArray{...
```

Here, caseArray is not the java type and it should be updated as follows.

```
String[] caseArray = new String[]{...
```

And third, I have set the initial value of `found` to `false` and if we use like this, no need to set `found = false` in `for` query.

Answer (score 0):

First of all there are couple of syntax issue with this code.

- the String array initialization is wrong

  ```
  String [] caseArray = new caseArray{"apple", "orange", "mango", "pineapple" };
  ```
- in `equals()` check String has a syntax error

  ```
  if(caseArray[i].equals(pineapple)){
  ```
- didn't initialize the boolean but you try to use that variable later.
- `break;` keyword is used outside a loop in an `if` condition.

I have corrected the syntax so that you can execute it.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            boolean found = false;
            String[] caseArray = { "apple", "orange", "mango", "pineapple" };
            for (int i = 0; i < caseArray.length; i++) {
                if (caseArray[i].equals("pineapple")) {
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (found) {
                System.out.println("product found");
                // break;
            } else {
                System.out.print("product not found");
                // break;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
product found
```

Comment: @KoushikMandal Thank you so much! The logic works, but at the end the same error comes up. Why does that happen?

Comment: What error you are talking about?

Can you please paste here?

Comment: @KoushikMandal Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException

Comment: @Ramnishanth I have updated code to catch and print the exception. Please copy paste updated code and run. Then if you get any exception please paste the stacktrace.